# how to set angular controller element using http get return values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-get

I am using http get function to get json array from service. How can I set response to controller **locations** element.

```
function MainCtrl($http,myService) {
    this.locations = null;
    myService.async().then(function(d) {
        ? = d;
    });
}
```

Response **d** is well-formed (JSON)

Comment: post a valid code, then ask for unexpected exceptions or behaviors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just take a reference to the current context and then use that variable reference in the callback

```
function MainCtrl($http,myService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.locations = []; // initialise properly
    myService.async().then(function(d) {
        vm.locations = d;
    });
}
```

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help. Just remember, when ever you enter a new function in JavaScript, `this` changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different approach to this problem too. I added my 'answer' for the sake of completeness. It is also possible to bind the *this* reference to your function. This can be achieved in two ways, by either using the [angular.bind()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) or the [native javascript bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass this reference.

e.g.:

```
function MainCtrl($http,myService) {
    this.locations = []; // initialise properly

    myService.async().then(function(d) {
        this.locations = d;
    }.bind(this));
}
```

P.S.: I tried to edited your answer and add this solutions to this problem of different scopes but it got rejected. For the following reason:

*This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer*

Not to take aim at the reviewers but they sure don't realize I can't post any comment with the current rep I have nor does it make sense to answer an answered question.